# Encrypt attachements in Outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, encryption, microsoft-outlook-2007

We have received new requirements from our customers that all files we attach e-mail must be encrypted with a password. The actual text of the e-mails do not need to be encrypted.

Some of our customers use [AxCrypt](http://www.axantum.com/axcrypt/), but I can not find any integration to Outlook 2007 for that.
I would like some tips for programs we can test. Ideally, we want it is freeware or open source. We can not require customers to buy the same program as we if it costs too much.

Answer (score 0):

When my company was asked to do this, we used a couple different solutions:

1. Exchange TLS - We setup our exchange servers to use TLS so that everything sent between us was encrypted. Takes a few minutes to setup, but there's no end-user requirements.
2. 7zip - For clients where the TLS option wouldn't work, end-users would create encrypted archives using AES encryption.

The second option is easy enough, and free - but it does require the end-user to remember to do it.